# Identifying each table row using SQl

Tags: php

I have created a table using HTML that retrieves data from my database. At the end of each row, I have manually added a submit button which is inside the while loop as the data is retireved from the database. Once the button is clicked, the session username is inserted into a table in the database. I also want it to enter other data of only the specific row. With what I have right now, no matter which button you click on any row, the data from the first row is only inserted.

Thanks for all your help.

In simpler words, on button click how do I select the data from that row where the button is present and insert it into the db?

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"; include "button.php"; echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
```

Button.php checks for the session_username and adds it to the database. I want it to also insert the "firstname" .

Comment: You need to show some code. Use the edit link. Sounds like a variable/logic mismatch. (Cut it down to the relevant parts please!)

Comment: why would you manipulate data from php, why not just display data in row, than do something onclick on each row which will edit the line you are clicking to, its fairly easy. who button.php as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a name to your submit buttons so you know which one was clicked.

Comment: The submit button is inside a While loop...How do i add the name to each and every submit button?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit[<?= $row['PersonID'] ?>]" />

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the page being reloaded, a simple way to do it is by having a separate  for each line of your table, something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<form action=""submit.php"">";
  echo "<input type=""hidden"" name=""FirstName"" value=""" . $row['FirstName'] . """>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type=""submit"" value=""Save""> </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

Pressing the button will submit the form to submit.php with a POST parameter called `FirstName` which contains the person's first name, and submit.php can do the database `INSERT`.